# Using Swipe support how to slide a menu back in?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, menu

I have included **jquery.mobile.custom.min.js** as I implemented swipe support for the carousel on my landing page.

I have however a menu that currently operates with a button, I am struggling now to implement swipe support to "close" the menu (basically a swipe to the left should equal a click on the button)

Relevant HTML:

```html
<body>
<!-- sidebar -->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <input type="checkbox" name="handler-left" class="handler" id="handler-left" onclick="null" />
     <div id = "menu">
            <ul> 
              <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
              <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
              <li><a href="portfolio.html#">Portfolio</a></li> 
              <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
     </div>

<div id="wrapper">
        <p id="button">
        <label for="handler-left" id="left" href="#">Menu</label>
        </p>
```

My dopey efforts at the script:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $("menu").swipeleft(function() {  
        $(this).parent().handler('left');  
    });  
});
```

Here is the CSS for handler:

```css
.handler {
    display: none; }
    #handler-left.handler:checked ~ #menu {
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transition: opacity 0s 0s;
      -moz-transition: opacity 0s 0s; }
      #handler-left.handler:checked ~ #wrapper {
        -webkit-transform: translate3D(40%, 0, 0);
        -moz-transform: translate3D(40%, 0, 0); }
        #handler-left.handler:checked ~ #wrapper #content {
          overflow: hidden; }
```

Progress update:

So I managed to detect a swipe on the entire document, now need to find a way to I guess toggle class? code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {               
 $(document).on("swipeleft",function(){               
    (".handler").??? });    });
```

UPDATE 2:

I actually found the solution.

Below is the code that did the trick:

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {  
             $(document).on("swipeleft",function(){
             document.getElementById('handler-left').click();

             // alert("you swiped left!");
});
    });
```

Comment: I think my major struggle is figuring out on what to let the swipe trigger

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(document).ready(function() {  
         $(document).on("swipeleft",function(){
         document.getElementById('handler-left').click();

         // alert("you swiped left!");
```

});
    });

Found the solution myself :)